# Is there any Chrome extension available for bypassing Googl ReCAPTCHA or even solve it?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, recaptcha, puppeteer, captcha

Basically I am looking for an extension to bypass Google ReCaptcha for my Puppeteer code for login.

Comment: Seeking recommendations for books, software libraries, or other off-site resources is off-topic for Stack Overflow. See: [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

[`puppeteer-extra-plugin-recaptcha`](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/tree/master/packages/puppeteer-extra-plugin-recaptcha) is what you're looking for.